# CUDA 5.0, compilation error

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, compiler-errors

The following piece of code gives an error and I cannot see any reason for it. Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
__global__ void thekernel(float *device_a, int CELLS, int LVLS) {

   int t_id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

   int INR = CELLS - 1;
   int col = INR - (threadIdx.x % CELLS);
   int row = t_id / CELLS;
   float power = (row / pow((float)LVLS, col)) % LVLS;
   device_a[t_id] = power;
 }
```

The compilation error states:

```
cudaMain.cu(11): error: expression must have integral or enum type
```

which is expression:

```
float power = (row / pow((float)LVLS, col)) % LVLS;
```

If I remove **"% LVLS"** from this expression the code compiles without any error.
The compilation string is:

```
nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -odir "" -M -o "cudaMain.d" "../cudaMain.cu"
nvcc --compile -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=compute_20 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20  -x cu -o  "cudaMain.o" "../cudaMain.cu"
```

### Hardware

My GPU card is: Quadro 6000 with compute capability 2.0

Comment: float pow(float,int) is not done yet maybe? Can you try pow(float,float) or pow(int,int)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik if i simply remove mod LVLS or (% LVLS) the error goes away.
If I break the statement into two:
power = (row / pow((float)LVLS, col))
power = power % LVLS

I get the error again on the second line (power = power % LVLS)

Comment: Maybe you have to take modulus of an integral type such as int or long. Maybe floats and doubles cannot be used for modulus operator target. It should auto cast although it doesnt need.

Comment: Yes you are right. Casting result of pow((float)LVLS, col) to integer worked all right. But this is quite interesting. Something out of my expectation.

Comment: Maybe because it has to obey C-99 ?

Comment: But is there any switch for nvcc that suggest to user something else than c99?

Answer (score 1):

Casting the power function to type **int** worked.

```
int denom = (int)pow((float)LVLS, (float)col);
int power = (row / denom) % LVLS;
```

Executed without any compilation errors. Interesting to know, in cuda, modulus operator is restricted to integers. (I am not so sure about this)

Comment: Not in CUDA, its a part of C and C++ standards that `%` operator applies only to integer types. It makes sense as, mathematically, remainder is a part of integer division, not decimal division.

Comment: For something similar in functionality to the modulo operator but defined for floating-point operands, take a look at the functions fmod(), remainder(), and remquo(). Note: These aren't particularly fast on any platform I have used, which includes CUDA.